# What is the difference between the OkHttp methods .toString() and .string()?

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

I have a snippet of code:

```
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
        try {
            Log.d("DEBUG POST=====>", response.body()!!.string())
        }catch(e:IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()

        }

    }
```

When I use `response.body()!!.string()` I get the correct output, and JSON body.

When I use: `response.body().toString()` I get `okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@c626d25`

Can anyone kindly tell me what is the difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`string()` isn't a valid Kotlin (or Java) method, as in neither of the languages define it. It's defined by OkHttp in [`ResponseBody`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/4258c913b30e018e25b21af98ce901cfc4de1c93/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/ResponseBody.kt#L171) and it's the correct way to get the actual string value of the class. it doesn't override `toString`, which means calls to `toString()` go to `Object` which returns the object in a form like you got. To be exact, it returns a hexadecimal representation of the object.

**TL:DR;** Java or Kotlin doesn't define a `string()` method, the OkHttp library does in the `ResponseBody` class. `toString` isn't overridden, making it return the hexadecimal representation of the class instead of the string value of the body. Use `string()` and not `toString()`

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation for OkHttp's ResponseBody](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html#string--), the `string()` function:

> Returns the response as a string decoded with the charset of the Content-Type header. If that header is either absent or lacks a charset, this will attempt to decode the response body in accordance to its BOM or UTF-8. Closes ResponseBody automatically.

In contrast, the `toString()` method that is on all Java/Kotlin objects, in this case is not defined for `ResponseBody`. In that case, the version on `java.lang.Object` will be called instead, and the standard implementation for that is to emit the object's class name and the object's hash code (as hex).

From the [JavaDoc for `Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

In short, these methods intentionally do different things.